# Which is the most specialized function template in the context of taking the address?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Consider this [example](https://godbolt.org/z/66Kx54e9K)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
template<class T>
void fun(T&){  //#1
    std::cout<<"selected\n";
}

template<class T>
void fun(T&&){}  //#2

int main() {
    void(*ptr)(int&) = &fun;  //#3
}
```

Both GCC and Clang report an error with the diagnosis "ambiguous". According to [temp.deduct.funcaddr#1], such two function templates are all viable in `#3`. Hence, [over.over#5] needs to apply here

> Any given function template specialization F1 is eliminated if the set contains a second function template specialization whose function template is more specialized than the function template of F1 according to the partial ordering rules of [temp.func.order].

To judge which is more specialized between `#1` and `#2`, [temp.deduct.partial#3.3] applies to them

> The types used to determine the ordering depend on the context in which the partial ordering is done:
>
> > - [...]
> > - In **other contexts the function template's function type** is used.

Hence, the P and A used to participate in **partial ordering** should be the function type of that two function templates, respectively. Take the function type of `#2` as P and the function type of `#1` as A. Deduce `P` from `A` is successful as per [temp.deduct.type#10]

> If P and A are function types that originated from deduction when taking the address of a function template ([temp.deduct.funcaddr]) or when deducing template arguments from a function declaration ([temp.deduct.decl]) and Pi and Ai are parameters of the top-level parameter-type-list of P and A, respectively, Pi is adjusted if it is a forwarding reference ([temp.deduct.call]) and Ai is an lvalue reference, in which case the type of Pi is changed to be the template parameter type (i.e., T&& is changed to simply T).

Conversely, Since we cannot deduce `T&` from `T&&`, hence the function template at `#1` is more specialized than the function template at `#2`. Hence the specialization of `#2` should be eliminated from the set. Ultimately, the set only contains exactly one specialization of `#1`. It should be unambiguous here. Why do GCC and Clang say the taking address is ambiguous?

Comment: msvc compiles https://godbolt.org/z/Kn8Pz64qa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GCC and Clang are wrong to yield and ambiguity in overload resolution, as per your own analysis.

This arguably relates to [CWG 1164](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1164), albeit not being [in the context of a function call](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.deduct.partial#3.1), the intent should arguably be similar as for the case of functions calls as per CWG 1164 [**emphasis** mine]:

> #### 1164. Partial ordering of f(T&) and f(T&&)
>
> Section: 13.10.3.2  [temp.deduct.call]     Status: C++11     Submitter: US     Date: 2010-08-03
>
> [Voted into the WP at the November, 2010 meeting.]
>
> N3092 comment US 77 The following example is ambiguous:
>
> ```
> template<typename T> int f(T&);
> template<typename T> int f(T&&);
> int i;
> int j = f(i);
> ```
>
> Because of the special deduction rule for lvalues passed to
> rvalue-reference parameters, deduction produces f(int&) for both
> templates, and they are indistinguishable.
>
> **Because f(T&) accepts a strict subset of the things that f(T&&) does,
> it should be considered more specialized by the partial ordering
> rules.**
>
> **Proposed resolution (August, 2010):** [...]

Your own analysis reaches an overload result which is aligned with CWG 1164 but for another context, which was never lifted in CWG 1164 and which is (arguably) less common.

---

<sub>We may note that both GCC and Clangs marks the resolution of CWG 1164 as `?`/`Unknown`:</sub>
<sub>- [GCC: C++ Defect Report Support in GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-dr-status.html)</sub>
<sub>- [C++ Defect Report Support in Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_dr_status.html)</sub>
<sub>So possibly it has only been partially implemented (OP's example is more of a corner use case than that of the CWG 1164).</sub>

Comment: The example in CWG1164 is a bit different from mine. `f(i);` the partial ordering occurs in the function call, hence the pair type used for deduction is their parameter types as per [temp.deduct.partial#3.1].